# Start and stop windows service on a Azure VM using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, windows-services, azure-virtual-machine

Using powershell, I need to do the following steps.
1. Login to Azure account.
2. Create a VM from the Image.
3. In the image , there is windows service.So when we created the VM, that windows service is already running on it.Stop that service.
4. Copy some binaries into the VM to a specific folder.
5. Start the service again.

Out of all these, I was able to acheive 1 and 2 steps. And I couldn't find any relevant procedure for rest of the steps.   Below is the script I have used to do 1 and 2.

```
Login-AzureRMAccount    

$UserName = "username@organization.com"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)    
New-AzureRmVm `
    -ResourceGroupName "RGN" `
    -Name "VMName" `
    -ImageName "ImageName" `
    -Location "West US" `
    -Credential $psCred
```

So can anyone help me or guide me how the rest of the steps be done.
Thanks in advance for your time.

**EDIT** : The command for stopping the service is
    Stop-Service -Name "CPS Dev UniSimServices" -Force

But this works, if I log into the VM and run this command. I want to connect to the newly created VM through powershell from the remote machine itself (without logging into it), and stop the service. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interact with the VM using extension without connecting into it. You can use the  PowerShell command with the custom script:

```
Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupAutomate" `
    -ExtensionName "IIS" `
    -VMName "myVM" `
    -Location "EastUS" `
    -Publisher Microsoft.Compute `
    -ExtensionType CustomScriptExtension `
    -TypeHandlerVersion 1.8 `
    -SettingString '{"commandToExecute":"powershell Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server; powershell Add-Content -Path \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Default.htm\" -Value $($env:computername)"}'
```

**Update**

If you really want to use a custom script for the extension, you can use the command like this:

```
Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup `
    -VMName myVM `
    -Location myLocation `
    -FileUri myURL `
    -Run 'myScript.ps1' `
    -Name DemoScriptExtension
```

For more details, see [Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmcustomscriptextension?view=azurermps-6.7.0).

Comment: thanks for replying. Here, is the computer name and VM name same?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, the computer name inside the vm the same with the vm name which you created.

Comment: @CrazyCoder If the answer is helpful or for more help, please let me know.

Comment: where should I write the script to stop the service? I couldn't understand what exactly this code is doing. If possible can you explain me in detail.Thanks

Comment: @CrazyCoder You can just add the cmdlet in `commandToExecute` with the PowerShell cmdlet [`Set-AzureRmExtension`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmextension?view=azurermps-6.7.0). Or you can use the custom script with the PowerShell [`Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmcustomscriptextension?view=azurermps-6.7.0). You can take a look at this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#powershell-deployment).

Comment: I have used this command after creating the VM on powershell.
Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName "RSG" `
    -ExtensionName "IIS" `
    -VMName "VMName" `
    -Location "West US" `
    -Publisher Microsoft.Compute `
    -ExtensionType CustomScriptExtension `
    -TypeHandlerVersion 1.8 `
    -SettingString '{"Get-Service 'Service Name'":"powershell Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server; powershell Add-Content -Path \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Default.htm\" -Value $($env:VMName)"}'
 
 It is saying " A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'RSG'."

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not able to format it properly in comments.

Comment: @CrazyCoder The command is just a sample. The arguments such as "myResourceGroupAutomate"、"IIS"、"myVM", etc, you should change them into your own arguments.

Comment: @CrazyCoder If the answer is helpful, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

To stop a service use the following command `Stop-Service -Name "NameOfService" -Force`, take a look on the docs of [Stop-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service?view=powershell-6) for any question. Then copy the files that you need via robocopy, Copy-Item or whatever and `Start-Service -Name "NameOfService"`. If you have any problem to copy files from your local or remote machine to your VM just post it.

As said in the other answer you can use the [Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmcustomscriptextension?view=azurermps-6.7.0), the following example executes in the VM a script upload to a Blob Storage account

```
Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Location $LocationName -VMName $ServersName -Name $scriptName -StorageAccountName $NameStorageAccount -FileName $fileName -Run $fileName -ContainerName $NameCOntainerStorage -Argument "-param1 $param1"
```

another option is using the command [Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/invoke-azurermvmruncommand?view=azurermps-6.7.0), for example

```
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $ServersName -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath "pathToFileExecute" -Parameter @{"Param" = "$Param"}
```

note: the argument -ScriptPath can be for example a shared path like \VM\e$\script.ps1 or local path.

last option is by using the [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6), for example:

```
Invoke-command -ComputerName $server -crdential $objectcredential -scriptblock {Stop-Service -Name "nameService" -force}
```